Determining the σ-Algebra and Pushforward Measure for the Euclidean Norm on ℝ²
I am working on an exercise that involves analyzing the function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x, y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, the Euclidean norm of a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I need to determine two things:

The $\sigma$-algebra generated by $f$, $\sigma(f)$.
The pushforward measure of the Lebesgue measure under $f$, denoted as $f_*\lambda$.

From my understanding, $\sigma(f)$ consists of all sets that can be described as annuli centered at the origin, as well as their complements and any unions of such sets. This encompasses sets whose preimages under $f$ are intervals or collections of intervals on the non-negative real line $\mathbb{R}^+$.
For the pushforward measure $f_*\lambda$, I believe it is constructed by extending the measure from the semi-ring of intervals in $\mathbb{R}^+$, utilizing the transformation properties of the function $f$.
I am seeking clarification and a more explicit determination of:

The $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(f)$: What are the specific characteristics and types of sets that form this $\sigma$-algebra?
The pushforward measure $f_*\lambda$: How is this measure explicitly calculated for sets within $\sigma(f)$? What is the formal approach to defining this measure, especially over the complex unions or intersections of sets described by $f$?

Any insights into the formal definitions and calculations for these components would be greatly appreciated.
